# Email notification when approaching Salesforce storage usage limit

Tags: limits

Is it possible to create an apex that will send an email notification when Salesforce is approaching certain percentage of its storage usage limit?

Answer (score 2):

No. There's no API to ascertain the current usage or limit, unless you want to resort to screen scraping, which is unreliable at best. However, emails are sent to administrators as storage reaches 100%, as described in Help and Training.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just want to clarify if the storage limit (100%) that is sending an email is for the Data Storage and File Storage? The storage usage that we want to have an email notification is for Data and File Storage usage.